# Steel mixture homework problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My problem is the following:

> In a particular steel mixture, $20 \%$ of it consists from chromium
>   and $10\%$ from nickel. How much of this steel mixture can be
>   produced, if we have $1200$kg of chromium and $900$kg of nickel. The
>   other steel ingredients don't limit the amount  of steel mixture we
>   can produce.
>
> a) $9 000$kg
>
> b) $7000$kg
>
> c) $6000$kg
>
> d) $4500$kg

[image]

My question is: Is the correct answer c) $6000$kg?

P.S. Please let me know if the task is unclear, I translated it from another language the best I could ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, with $ 1200 $ kg of chromium you can produce at most $6000 $ kg of steel. With your quantities of nichel you can produce $9000 $ kg of steel Instead.  But now you have to deal with the fact you don't have enough chromium. So 6000 is the correct answer.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Riccardo, I thought so too, thnx =) Appreciate it

Comment: Not a problem. During high school I made lots of these problems, you have to calculate (for every ingredient) the maximun theoric quantity of product given only one limited ingredient, and then choosing the least quantity :)